# How to Use for loop with data in terraform?

Tags: terraform

I am trying to get the `cluster_identifier` and `aws_db_snapshot` for certain databases using a data file. My data.tf file looks like this :-

```
data "aws_rds_cluster" "cluster" {
  cluster_identifier = var.rds_sources
}

data "aws_db_snapshot" "db" {
  db_instance_identifier = var.rds_sources
  most_recent            = true
}
```

where `rds_sources` is a `list(string)`. But when i do `terraform plan` i keep running into :-

```
Error: Incorrect attribute value type
│ 
│   on ../data.tf line 2, in data "aws_rds_cluster" "cluster":
│    2:   cluster_identifier = var.rds_sources
│     ├────────────────
│     │ var.rds_sources is a list of string, known only after apply
│ 
│ Inappropriate value for attribute "cluster_identifier": string required.
╵
╷
│ Error: Incorrect attribute value type
│ 
│   on ../data.tf line 6, in data "aws_db_snapshot" "db":
│    6:   db_instance_identifier = var.rds_sources
│     ├────────────────
│     │ var.rds_sources is a list of string, known only after apply
│ 
│ Inappropriate value for attribute "db_instance_identifier": string
│ required.
```

My question is how can i use for loop to get the necessary information? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said "for loop" so I assume you are wanting to use [for_each](https://www.terraform.io/language/meta-arguments/for_each) although you could also use [count](https://www.terraform.io/language/meta-arguments/count) here.

```
data "aws_rds_cluster" "cluster" {
  for_each = toset(var.rds_sources)

  cluster_identifier = each.key
}

data "aws_db_snapshot" "db" {
  for_each = toset(var.rds_sources)

  db_instance_identifier = each.key
  most_recent            = true
}
```

Note that you may need to be using [aws_db_cluster_snapshot](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/db_cluster_snapshot) instead of `aws_db_snapshot` depending on your database engine.

Comment: Thank you however when i am trying to use it in my main.tf file i keep running into :- 

 ```on ../main.tf line 75, in resource "aws_iam_policy" "source_application":
│   75:     cluster_data_sources  = data.aws_db_cluster_snapshot.cluster.id
│ 
│ Because data.aws_db_cluster_snapshot.cluster has "for_each" set, its
│ attributes must be accessed on specific instances.
│ 
│ For example, to correlate with indices of a referring resource, use:
│     data.aws_db_cluster_snapshot.cluster[each.key]
```

Comment: It probably needs to be `cluster_data_sources = data.aws_db_cluster_snapshot.cluster[*].id`. Those data sources you are using expect a single identifier and they return a single resource. So you end up with a set of data sources, not a list of IDs, and you have to pull those IDs out accordingly. If you need more help, include all the relevant terraform code in your question.